# HQL NamedQuery with inner join on a HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, named-query

I am developing a JSF project and using Hibernate over mysql

as you may know (it is in the Hibernate documentation), joins use associations between entities. So a sample correct query with an inner join will be :

```
select from Person p join p.classes c where c.room = :roomNum
```

bu in my case the associated entity is a HashMap which contains the desired entity.
some code will help :

```
public FamilyGuy{

private String name;
private BigDecimal income;
private HashMap<String, Child> children = new HashMap<Language, Child>();
....
} 

public Child{
private String name;
private BigDecimal expenses;
....
}
```

what i need is a query like this (the below query is not working) :

```
select from FamilyGuy oppressed inner join Child happy where happy.expenses < :threshold
```

the exception i am getting is :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Path expected for join!
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f from FamilyGuy f 
inner join f.children child
where child.expenses < :threshold
```

just like with any other toMany association.

As you said; joins use associations. So you can't specify the name of an entity (`join Child`), but must specify an association: `join f.children`... just like in the example at the start of your question.

Comment: thank you for brief and yet mature answer, in your query , are you selecting the FamilyGuy? if i wanted to select the  child will this query be correct : select child from FamilyGuy f 
inner join f.children child
where child.expenses < :threshold